# jquery hint disappears when i click submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

when user1 and user2 do not select anything from radio box the jquery validation triggers but removes the jquery hint from the 'fav food' textbox. how do i prevent this?

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/NevcG/1/

Comment: @ThomasClayson oh sorry i didnt know that (im new). i removed this now nothing is showing in the textbox. please see jsfiddle.net/NevcG/4

Comment: I've added a comment to my answer dude. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of this code at the bottom:

It pretty obviously sets the value of `input.hint` to nothing on submit of a form. Remove this and it'll work as you expect.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $('input.hint').val('');
  return true;
});
```

Comment: i removed this now nothing is showing in the textbox. please see http://jsfiddle.net/NevcG/4/

Comment: you must have changed something else: here is a modification of your ORIGINAL jsfiddle - all I've done is deleted the function at the end: http://jsfiddle.net/NevcG/5/

Comment: yes all working but only one problem. it submits the jquery hint into the database if left blank and it can be left blank as its an optional field

Comment: ok, then you need to edit your submit function... I'll go make a new fiddle

Comment: thanks working great now but when i refresh the page the jquery hint becomes text in the textfield. can i prevent this?